# Calculator in lex and yacc

Tags: yacc, lex

I am trying to create a calculator by using lex and yacc. However I can not understand how can I give operator precedence to this program? I could not find any information about it. Which code do I need to add to my project to calculate correctly?

Yacc file is:

```
%{
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int yylex();
void yyerror(const char *s);
%}
%token INTEGER

%left  '*'  '/'
%left  '+'  '-'

%%
program:
       program line | line

line:
    expr ';' { printf("%d\n",$1); } ; | '\n'

expr:
    expr '+' term { $$ = $1 + $3; } 
    | expr '-' term { $$ = $1 - $3; }
    | expr '*' term { $$ = $1 * $3; } 
    | expr '/' term { $$ = $1 / $3; } 
    | expr '%' term { $$ = $1 % $3; }
    | expr '^' term { $$ = $1 ; }
    | term { $$ = $1; }

term:
    INTEGER { $$ = $1; }
%%
void yyerror(const char *s) { fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",s); return ; }
int main(void) { /*yydebug=1;*/ yyparse(); return 0; }
```

Lex file is:

```
%{
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void yyerror(char*);
extern int yylval;
#include "calc.tab.h" 
#include<time.h>
%}

%%

[ \t]+ ; //skip whitespace
[0-9]+ {yylval = atoi(yytext); return INTEGER;}

[-+*/%^] {return *yytext;}
\n {return *yytext;}
; {return *yytext;}
. {char msg[25]; sprintf(msg,"%s <%s>","invalid character",yytext); yyerror(msg);}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
%left  '*'  '/'
%left  '+'  '-'
```

Precedence declarations are specified in the order from lowest precedence to highest. So in the above code you give `*` and `/` the lowest precedence level and `+` and `-` the highest. That's the opposite order of what you want, so you'll need to switch the order of these two lines. You'll also want to add the operators `%` and `^`, which are currently part of your grammar, but not your precedence annotations.

With those changes, you'll now have specified the precedence you want, but it won't take effect yet. Why not? Because precedence annotations are used to resolve ambiguities, but your grammar isn't actually ambiguous.

The way you've written the grammar, with only the left operand of all operators being `expr` and the right operand being `term`, there's only one way to derive an expression like `2+4*2`, namely by deriving `2+4` from `expr` and `2` from term (because deriving `4*2` from `term` would be impossible since `term` can only match a single number). So your grammar treats all operators as left-associative and having the same precedence and your precedence annotations aren't considered at all.

In order for the precedence annotations to be considered, you'll have to change your grammar, so that both operands of the operators are `expr` (e.g. `expr '+' expr` instead of `expr '+' term`). Written like that an expression like `2+4*2` could either be derived by deriving `2+4` from `expr` as the left operand and `2` from `expr` as the right operand or `2` as the left and `4*2` as the right and this ambiguity will be resolved using your precedence annotations.

Comment: I have already tried to switch them and result is not changed

Comment: @DesktopXx Ah, I only saw the wrong order of the precedence annotation and didn't notice that your grammar was unambiguous (and also contains more operators than you've specified the precedence for). See my edited answer.